# js, очистка буфера (замена пустым значение) в setTimeout

Tags: javascript, события, click, settimeout, clipboard

Успешно происходит копирование в буфер обмена по клику на элементе

```
function copyToClipboard(input) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(input);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    return successful;
};

document.getElementById('js_clear_clipboard').addEventListener("click", function() {
    var res = copyToClipboard(this.value); // res - true
});
```

Вычитал, что document.execCommand('copy') выполняется только в событиях. Но если выполнить копирование этого же элемента, программным вызовом события в setTimeout, то document.execCommand('copy') возвращает false, и соответственно в буфер ничего не скопировано:

```
setTimeout(function(){    
    document.getElementById('js_clear_clipboard').addEventListener("click", function() {
        var res = copyToClipboard(this.value);
    });
    var event = new Event('click');
    document.getElementById('js_clear_clipboard').dispatchEvent(event);
}, 5000);
```

Нужно это для того, чтобы по происшествии какого-то времени буфер перетирался.
Подскажите, в чём трабла и как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что запись в буфер возможна только по прямому действию пользователя на странице, например клик на элементе. Это поведение сделано для безопасности системы что бы копирование в буфер не могло произойти тогда когда пользователь этого не ожидает.

То есть в `setTimeout` такое сделать не получится.

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) очень подробное описание возможности копирования в буфер.